# For $p$ prime and for $1 ≤ e ∈ Z$ the prime-power $p^e$-th cyclotomic polynomial $Φ_{p^e} (x)$ is irreducible in $Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

This is part of **'Abstract Algebra,  Paul Garrett,  243-244p'**

Recall that
$Φ_{p^e}(x) = Φ_p(x^{p^{e-1}}) = \frac{x^{p^{e}}-1}{x^{p^{e-1}}-1} $

First, we check that $p$ divides all but the highest-degree coefficient of $f(x)$. To do so, map everything to $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, by reducing coefficients modulo p. For $e ≥ 1$
$(x + 1)^{p^{e-1}} = x^{p^{e-1}} + 1$ ($mod$ $p)$

Therefore, in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$
$f(x) = Φ_p((x+1)^{p^{e-1}}) = \frac{(x+1)^{p^{e}}-1}{(x+1)^{p^{e-1}}-1}$

$ = ((x+1)^{p^{e-1}})^{p-1}+((x+1)^{p^{e-1}})^{p-2}+...+((x+1)^{p^{e-1}})+1$

........................................................................................................

$ = (x^{p^{e-1}}+1)^{p-1}+(x^{p^{e-1}}+1)^{p-2}+...(x^{p^{e-1}}+1)+1$

$ = \frac{(x^{p^{e-1}}+1)^p-1}{(x^{p^{e-1}}+1)-1}$

$ = \frac{x^{p^{e-1}}+1-1}{x^{p^{e-1}}}$

$ = \frac{x^{p^e}}{x^{p^{e-1}}}$

$ = x^{p^{e-1}(p-1)}$

........................................................................................................

in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ Thus, all the lower coefficients are divisible by $p$.
To determine the constant coefficient of $f(x)$, again use

$Φ_{p^e}(x) = Φ_p(x^{p^{e-1}})$

to compute

constant coefficient of $f = f(0) = Φ_{p^e} (1) = Φ_p(1^{p^{e-1}}) = Φ_p(1) = p$

as in the prime-order case. Thus, $p^2$ does not divide the constant coefficient of f. Then apply Eisenstein’s criterion and Gauss’ lemma to obtain the irreducibility

---

I don't understand ........... part

Based on the assumption of $p = 5, e = 2 $ from Wolfram Alpha,
$\frac{(x + 1)^{25} - 1}{(x + 1)^5 - 1} = ((x+1)^5)^4+((x+1)^5)^3+((x+1)^5)^2+(x+1)^5+1$

$≠ (x^5+1)^4+(x^5+1)^3+(x^5+1)^2+(x^5+1)+1$

Comment: It is equal modulo $5$ which  means that $ ((x+1)^5)^4+((x+1)^5)^3+((x+1)^5)^2+(x+1)^5+1 - ( (x^5+1)^4+(x^5+1)^3+(x^5+1)^2+(x^5+1)+1) = 5 f(x)$ for some $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$